# request.getAttribute in jsp is giving null value

Tags: jsp, struts

So in my Action class I have the following code.

```
public ActionForward detailsForUploadForm(ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    try {
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.1
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // prevents caching at the
        // proxy server



        request.setAttribute("filePath", filePath);

    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

And in my jsp file, I have the following

```
<html>String path = (String)session.getAttribute("path"); 
String filePath = (String)request.getAttribute("filePath");</html>
<form> <table>
 <input type="hidden" name="filePath" id="filePath" value="<%=filePath%>"/>
 </form>
 </table>
```

The problem is, I am getting the value in my java class but in my jsp file i am getting the value as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>String path = (String)session.getAttribute("path"); 
String filePath = (String)request.getAttribute("filePath");</html>.
```

What is this code ?  You intended to write a java code inside scriptlet `<% %>`, but you have written in inside `<html>` tag. That won't set any variable in JSP. Instead this code will be displayed as it is on your page as text.

If you want to access request attribute in JSP, best way would be Expression language. Also you won't need above code in scriptlet.

Just use `${filePath}`

```
 <input type="hidden" name="filePath" id="filePath" value="${filePath}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo error. I am writing it inside the scriptlet. I tried using the EL Expression, still getting the value as null. I am importing all the required class files and libraries in my jsp file. when I debug I'm getting the value in my action class. But when I'm printing in console I get "null" value.

Comment: @sam where are you initalizing filePath variable

Comment: I am declaring the variable in my action class, getting the value from bean, and storing it in request object as attribute and sending it to JSP. In JSP I'm initializing and assigning the value in the scriptlet.

Comment: String filePath = (String)request.getAttribute("filePath");

Comment: @sam just remove the sciptlet code in JSP. Keep just the EL code as mentioned above in answer

Comment: Thank you. now I'm getting the value. I included the EL code and tried it wasn't coming, then i refreshed the page. its working fine. lol

Comment: @sam : refresh couldn't have fixed it though :) . You can accept answer, so that question will be marked as answered and closed

Answer (score 1):

if you using the struts to display the values then use this for display

```
<s:property value="%{#request.AttributeName}" />
```

Comment: are you using struts...? to display value

Comment: Yes, I'm using Struts 1.2.

Comment: No, I'm not using RequestDispatcher. I am using mapping.findForward method to forward to the respective page which is configured in struts-config.xml

Comment: then try above answer for display... before that you have to import the struts tags in jsp like this <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>